# Can anyone identify the issue within this loop on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a loop that copies two cells "assetTag" and "assetDescription" in another workbook (Asset Register), and pastes it in my template workbook "FAT" (Fixed Asset Template), Cells "A3" and "B3". Then the workbook is saved as a concatenation of the assetTag and assetDescription.

Once saved, the Loop then clears these cells in the FAT template and reruns the loop, but incrementaly 1 further down the list in my Asset Register until its at the end of the list, then we move onto the next asset owner.

Onto the problem...
The workbooks that have been saved, the asset tags and descriptions do not match to the saved name of the workbook. The workbook names are always named the cell above the in my Asset Register

```
For Each ownerCell In ownerNameRange
     ownerName = ownerCell.Value
        
     If Not IsEmpty(ownerName) Then
         Set ownerSheet = FAR.Worksheets(ownerName)

         assetCount = ownerSheet.Cells(ownerSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
         ' newRow = 3 'Reset newRow for each owner
    
        For i = 7 To assetCount
            With FAT
                .Range("A3").ClearContents
                .Range("B3").ClearContents
            End With
            assetTag = CStr(ownerSheet.Cells(i, 18).Value) ' Assuming asset tag is in column R (15th column)
            assetDescription = CStr(ownerSheet.Cells(i, 11).Value) ' Assuming asset description is in column K (11th column)
     
            newRow = 3 ' Update with the appropriate row number
        
            FAT.Cells(3, 1).Value = assetTag
            FAT.Cells(3, 2).Value = assetDescription
       
            'save the workbook
            On Error Resume Next
            wbFAT.SaveAs masterPath & ownerName & "\" & assetTag & " - " & assetDescription & ".xlsx"
      
            With FAT
                .Range("A3").ClearContents
                .Range("B3").ClearContents
            End With
     '      On Error GoTo 0
        Next i
    End If

Next ownerCell
```

Comment: I would also recommend stepping through the code that is the easiest way to find a problem like this (besides just thinking about the code). Debugging tips: [VBA Debugging](https://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/programming-excel-vba-debugging-for.html) (learn to fish blah blah)

Comment: @topsail Hi topsail, thanks for the comment. The weird part is when I debug and step into, I hover my cursor over assetTag & assetDescription and they present the right asset tag, which is line with what has already been printed onto the template. When I continue with pressing F8, the script then runs fully and I cant take in where the error is happening.

But thanks for your suggestion. I'll take a look.

Comment: Just as another note when debugging I recommend you to comment out `on error resume next` as you really want to know if there is an error happening while you are debugging. For instance, it's possible the changes are not actually saved because (for instance) the file already exists or some other problem ... so you are not getting the saved workbook from this iteration and that's confusing.

Comment: You have not shown the full code as there is no `Sub ... End Sub`. It may not be the problem in this case but put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables, add some sample data. Then we will be able to suggest how to tackle this. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement